# Where to find a list of all jQuery events?

Tags: jquery

I really did try Google and jQuery documentation for this and I give up.

I need event names. No - I don't need to load them with code, I need them as HTML page, you know, to read and check what was the exact name of this event I've just forgotten. I'm sure there are hidden somwhere around the web laughing at me :)

It's pointless for me (or anyone) to ask here, "hey, how to attach a code when jQuery.ajax starts". I know, jQuery .ajax() triggers some global and local events, I know, if I'll waste another 15 minutes for reading whole .ajax() documentation I'll find it, but it's not my point. If you forget rarely used HTML tag name or syntax you just type "HTML tags" in google and find your tag in less than 10 seconds. Try it with jQuery event names :) "Window events" returns quite good documetation by Microsoft.

I'd rather waste my time for really good question: **where to find a list of all jQuery events?** It would be cool if they had some sort of description, but the most important are names.

I don't need any particular one of them. I need all of them in one place.

It's braindead easy when it comes to "class methods and properties". I know the code can define any number of custom events, but first: DOMDocument defines its defaults, JavaScript window defines its own and jQuery itself defines its own. Is there a list?

Comment: I'm not agree with you : it's very simply to find jquery events. There is all you need on jquery official website. http://api.jquery.com/category/events/

Comment: If you couldn't find this using Google you really need to uninstall your internet.

Comment: I was looking for "ajaxStart". You won't find it like that. What you have on jQuery site is a list of... It looks like methods to me. Methods which can be used to bind events. They don't cover ALL available window or document events. Even jQuery itself can trigger ajax events, they are explained, I've found them 5 minutes later. Well, you probably didn't expect someone might look for something less obvious :)

Comment: Before you try to out-clever each other, take a look at the suggested page. That page mentions "on" and "triggerHandler", which are not events.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check out my jQuery cheat sheet at http://learningcsharpnet.blogspot.com/2011/05/and-now-for-something-completely.html

Comment: @Andy E - It's amazing what you can do with a reasonably simple XSL stylesheet and the XML dump of the jQuery docs.  ;-)

Comment: then you deserve the +1 all the more :-) clever!

Answer (score 3):

Events in jQuery are just DOM events — except for a few exceptions that are provided for convenience — so you're not really looking for jQuery events.  That's the reason you're having a hard time finding them.

Since the events supported by each browser differ you really need to be looking at either a place like [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/), for compatibility tables, or each vendor's support site like [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element#Event_Handlers) or [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533051%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Remove the `on` prefix for any event when binding with jQuery.

Comment: Yeah, i know. The exact event I was looking for was "ajaxStart" which is triggered by jQuery. It is documented within .ajax() page of jQuery documentation. I din't want to read it n-th time, but eventualy I had to :) I was looking for it, because I used it in my own code, but the code is huge and I forgot where it was :)